# How is a 3D tensor indexed by two 3D tensors?

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a 3-D tensor `x_k`. I have another two 3-D tensors `h_att` and `i_att`, which work as indexes.   I want to know how `q = x_k[h_att,i_att]` works in detail.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
```

```
x_k = torch.arange(1,25).reshape(2,4,3)
```

```
x_k
tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9],
         [10, 11, 12]],

        [[13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18],
         [19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24]]])
```

```
i_att = torch.tensor([[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,0]]])
```

```
i_att
tensor([[[0, 1],
         [1, 2],
         [2, 3],
         [3, 0]]])
```

```
h_att = torch.arange(2).reshape(2, 1, 1).long()
```

```
h_att
tensor([[[0]],

        [[1]]])
```

```
q = x_k[h_att,i_att]
```

```
q
tensor([[[[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6]],

         [[ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[ 7,  8,  9],
          [10, 11, 12]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [ 1,  2,  3]]],


        [[[13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18]],

         [[16, 17, 18],
          [19, 20, 21]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24]],

         [[22, 23, 24],
          [13, 14, 15]]]])
```

Why is the output dimension (2,4,2,3) ?

Besides, if I change `i_att` to a 2-D tensor `i_att = torch.tensor([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,0]])`, the result is same as previous q. Why?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, you have too many questions. You should edit and refine your post. Asking something like "how to get this or that result", "I expect this result but got this"... will garner more answers.

Comment: PyTorch indexing mirrors the indexing used in numpy. The numpy documentation covers indexing pretty thoroughly (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#), I think the [advanced indexing section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) should be of interest.

Comment: From the docs "Advanced indices always are broadcast and iterated as one" which means `h_att` and `i_att` must have compatible shapes to allow for such broadcasting. If you reduce the unitary dimesions they can't broadcast anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In [advanced indexing section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), advanced indices in numpy should be

```
result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
                           ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
```

Since pytorch indexing mirrors the indexing used in numpy, I think first both h_att with shape (2, 1, 1) and i_att with shape (1, 4, 2) should be broadcast together with shape (2, 4, 2). Note that because the shape of  x_k is (2, 4, 3), `x_k[h_att,i_att]` means that elements in h_att should be less than 2 - the first dimension of x_k and elements in i_att should be less than 4 - the second dimension of x_k.

Let's see how this works in detail. The first element in result is `q[0,0,0] = x_k[h_att[0,0,0], i_att[0,0,0]] = x_k[0,0] = [1, 2, 3]`. Next element is `q[0,0,1] = x_k[h_att[0,0,1], i_att[0,0,1]] = x_k[0,1] = [4, 5, 6]`.

We repeat this process for all elements of h_att and i_att. The last element in result is `q[2,4,2] = x_k[h_att[2,4,2], i_att[2,4,2]] = x_k[1,0] = [13,14,15]`. We collect the final tensor of shape (2, 4, 2, 3) - shape of (2,4,2) like i_att and h_att with an additional dimetion of size 3, same as the third dimention of x_k.

If we change i_att to a 2-D tensor of shape (4, 2), it will be boardcast with shape (2,4,2). Therefore, the result ramains same.

Comment: In general, the shape of the resultant array will be the concatenation of the shape of the index array (or the shape that all the index arrays were broadcast to) with the shape of any unused dimensions (those not indexed) in the array being indexed. -from numpy https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing